# use INSERT INTO VALUES WHERE ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, insert, where-clause

I am trying the following query and it just doesn't store any values into the table.

Column Tienda is set to unique. The pk is Codigo and the query is:

```
$asignaciones = $db->query("
INSERT INTO  `Asignaciones` (
    `Codigo` , `Tienda` , `Apertura` , `Cierre_20_00` , `Cierre_20_30` , `Cierre_21_00` , `Sanitarios` , `Barrer_Mat` , `Barrer_Vesp` , `Trapear_Mat` , `Trapear_Vesp` , `Limpiar_Ventanales_y_Vitrinas` , `Fecha` , `Encargada` , `Supervisora` )
VALUES (NULL ,  '$Tienda',  '$Apertura',  '$Cierre_20_00',  '$Cierre_20_30',  '$Cierre_21_00',  '$Sanitarios',  '$Barrer_Mat',  '$Barrer_Vesp',  '$Trapear_Mat',  '$Trapear_Vesp',  '$Limpiar_Ventanales_y_Vitrinas',  '$Fecha',  '$Encargada', '$Supervisora' 
WHERE Tienda = '$MiTienda') 

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Apertura`= '$Apertura', `Cierre_20_00` = '$Cierre_20_00', `Cierre_20_30` ='$Cierre_20_30', `Cierre_21_00`= '$Cierre_21_00', `Sanitarios` ='$Sanitarios', `Barrer_Mat`= '$Barrer_Mat', `Barrer_Vesp`='$Barrer_Vesp' , `Trapear_Mat`='$Trapear_Mat' , `Trapear_Vesp` ='$Trapear_Vesp', `Limpiar_Ventanales_y_Vitrinas`='$Limpiar_Ventanales_y_Vitrinas' , `Fecha`= '$Fecha', `Encargada`='$Encargada' , `Supervisora`= '$Supervisora'");
```

Current row values are:

```
Codigo|Tienda|Apertura|Cierre_20_00|Cierre_20_30|Cierre_21_00|Sanitarios|Barrer_Mat|Barrer_Vesp|Trapear_Mat|Trapear_Vesp|Limpiar_Ventanales_y_Vitrinas|Fecha         |Encargada|Supervisora
2     |1010  |  0     | 0          |    0       |   0        |  0       |   0      |    0      |    0      |    0       |   0                         | 0000-00-00   |  0      |    0
```

What is wrong with my query? $MiTienda is = 1010 .  I tested by adding all other values to 4 and the date with todays date but it doesnt update. I am wondering if I should drop the Code Column and make Tienda PK?

Comment: Does your query executes? It seems mysql does not support "WHERE" in the place you have used. It seemed, it's just a bad syntax

Comment: WHERE is for SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE, not for INSERT.

Comment: ok, let me try removing it from there. could I place it at the end of the ON DUPLICATE?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `SET` in here `KEY UPDATE Apertura = '$Apertura',`  so `KEY UPDATE SET Apertura = '$Apertura',`  Maybe it's optional? Not sure but that is how I have always done it...

Comment: Thanks for being so eiger to do -1, not that it helps me resolve my problem and none of the previous suggestions have worked . If anyone else can contribute I would be very appretiated.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Remember when asking questions to be specific about the results you want and the results you're getting. This question is borderline "doesn't work, help!" which is really difficult to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that my variables were not being pushed through from the form in the previous page. That is why it stored nothing.  I used print_r($_SESSION); in the page with the query above to find out.